# What does it take to get the splunk logger running with docker-compose?

Tags: logging, docker, splunk

I'm trying to get the splunk log driver working with docker-compose

I've setup an instance of splunk Enterprise with outcoldman/splunk:6.4.1 and have turned on HEC with SSL turned on.

If I simply use docker alone to start up a container, like nginx, everything goes as expected.

```
docker run --name nginx -d --publish 80:80 --log-driver=splunk --log-opt splunk-token={my-token} --log-opt splunk-url=https://{my-host}:8088 --log-opt splunk-insecureskipverify=true nginx
```

But if I try to specify the same values in docker-compose v1 or v2, it fails with

> ERROR: Failed to initialize logging driver: EOF

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    logging:
      driver: splunk
      options:
        splunk-url: https://{my-host}:8080
        splunk-token: {my-token}
        splunk-insecureskipverify: 'true'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong port - serves me right for working late. Port 8088 is what I was looking for. It works like a dream.

Comment: Great to hear! What source type did you set for the HTTP Event Collector? I'm still struggling to get logging work...